# HatDash is Non-Fantastical

Tags: bug, status-completed, winterbash

The new [HatDash campaign](http://hatdash.com/) has the old title for SFF in its footer.

[image: Freehand hat]

You can see the differences here:

[image]

Comment: I can't repro... refresh your cache. I mean, why would hats change the _software revision_?

Comment: @badp Repo'd. I figured it wasn't running any actual revision; but was a static page made from the 2011.12.15.3 template. (Your comment is a little unclear. This doesn't have anything to do with the hat setting, if that's how you read it.)

Comment: Why don't I own this anymore?  **EDIT**: Interestingly, this comment showed up in my global inbox, from me.

Comment: +1 for the freehand hat!

Comment: Oh *no wonder* I couldn't see the problem when I looked at this from my phone... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UN-ACC-EPT-AB-LE.

Thus fixed.

Comment: Why is it still underlined?

Comment: Also, what happened to my account during the migration?